# Add Post support to Hubot

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, http-post, hubot

I am trying to add the [`http-post-say.coffee`](https://github.com/github/hubot-scripts/blob/master/src/scripts/http-post-say.coffee) script to a hubot app which is hosted on Heroku.

The documentation indicates that once you add the script then it creates the `'/hubot/say'` route which accepts post requests in the following format.

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/hubot/say -d message=lala -d room='#dev'
```

I added the script and modified the url but I received the following error:
`Cannot POST /hubot/say`

My next step was to add some dependencies. I noticed that other apps using `robot.router.post` had these dependencies.

```
"htmlparser": "1.7.6",
"connect": "2.3.4",
"connect_router": "1.8.6",
"scoped-http-client": "0.9.7"
```

I deployed my changes but I still receive `Cannot POST /hubot/say` when I try to hit that route.

Is there anything that I'm missing? I'm not very familiar with Node.js or hubot.

Comment: which folder do you add in? `scripts`?

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: solved? i tried your script, it works fine http://localhost:8080/hubot/say?message=lala&room=#dev

Comment: When you added the `http-post-say.coffee` script did you also quit and restart the hubot instance? Changes don't take effect unless the hubot restarts. Also you said you deployed to heroku, were you expecting the heroku hubot to respond to localhost:8080? Or did you also have a local instance running for testing?

Comment: could it be a permissions issue on the `http-post-say.coffee` file?

Answer (score 2):

You have to understand that once you push your code on to heroku and make it run there, the URL no longer would be `localhost` but the actual heroku URL related to the machine that was created when you did `heroku create`.

The URL should look something like:

```
curl -X POST `http://herokumachinename/hubot/say -d message=lala -d room='#dev'`
```

Answer (score 1):

To load a built-in script in Hubot, you must add it to `hubot-scripts.json`, e.g.:

```
["http-post-say.coffee"]
```

(Since the script itself looks fine and it sounds like you've pushed to Heroku (restarting Hubot) it's the only thing I can think of that would explain it not working.)